# @Transactional does not work in sub-thread in Quarkus?

Tags: multithreading, transactions, quarkus

I wrote three files code below（simplify）:

```
//Resource:
@RequestScoped
@Path("/task/ledger")
public class TaskController {

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    @Transactional
    @POST
    @Path("/start/{id}")
    public int createLedgerTask(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        LedgerTaskOverview overview = LedgerTaskOverview.findById(id);
        DataTask task = new DataTask(overview, dnsServer, elasticSearchClient);
        threadPool.execute(task);
        return 0;
    }
}

//Thread:
public class DataTask implements Runnable {
    public DataTask(LedgerTaskOverview overview,
                    DNSServer dnsServer,
                    ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient) {
        this.overview = overview;
        this.dnsServer = dnsServer;
        this.elasticSearchClient = elasticSearchClient;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ManagedContext requestContext = Arc.container().requestContext();
        if (!requestContext.isActive()) {
            requestContext.activate();
        }
        //do something...
        overview.persist();
    }
}

//Bean
@Entity
@Data //Lombok annotation
public class LedgerTaskOverview extends PanacheEntityBase {
    // fields ...
}
```

While request it shows me the error massege:
`Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one` at line `overview.persist();` in Thread class.

Toal error message is:

```
Exception in thread "pool-29-thread-1" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one.
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.persist(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:114)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.ForwardingEntityManager.persist(ForwardingEntityManager.java:27)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:77)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.persist(JpaOperations.java:59)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase.persist(PanacheEntityBase.java:56)
    at chain.B.ledger.LedgerTaskOverview.persist(LedgerTaskOverview.java:78)
    at chain.B.ledgerTask.tcp.DataTask.initDNSLoadBalance(DataTask.java:152)
    at chain.B.ledgerTask.tcp.DataTask.run(DataTask.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Afaik, `@Transactional` will not work if the instace is not created by the bean context. The proxy and/or interceptor is doing the actual magic, so this behaviour is expected. This is - by the way - the reason why `@Transactional` should not be used on `private` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just like mentioned in the comment, CDI annotations will not work for instances created manually with `new`. Yet there is a problem here - you need to manually create a "piece of work" and execute asynchronously. One way to do it in a managed environment is to split the code/behavior from the data. The code implementing the desired behavior is a managed object - an `@ApplicationScoped` bean here. It operates on the data, which is a POJO containing the necessary information to execute the behavior. E.g.:

POJO:

```java
public class Data {
  private String overviewId; // don't use a connected object, this will run in a different transaction!
  private DNSServer dnsServer;
  private ElasticSearchClient elasticSearchClient;
  // accessors
}
```

Behavior:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataTask {
  @Resource // or is it @Inject in Quarkus? please experiment a bit :)
  private ManagedExecutorService threadPool; // use the ManagedExecutorService anyway!
                                             // configure it from withing Quarkus config

  @Transactional
  public void run(Data data) {
    LedgerTaskOverview overview = LedgerTaskOverview.findById(id);
    ManagedContext requestContext = Arc.container().requestContext();
    if (!requestContext.isActive()) {
      requestContext.activate();
    }
    //do something...
    overview.persist();
  }
}
```